# ArcGIS Arcade-Expression - values from several fields

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade

I am looking for an Arcade Expression for ArcGIS Online which does the following:

```
If the value from field A is 222,333 or 444 OR
If the value from field B is 222,333 or 444 OR
If the value from field C is 222,333 or 444
return "Problem detected"

else return "Everything fine"
```

I have just found a solution for one field, but it does not take care of Field B or field C:

```
if ( $feature.FieldA == 111) {
return "everything fine"
}
else if ( $feature.FieldA == 222) {
return "Problem detected"
}
else if ( $feature.FieldA == 333) {
return "Problem detected"
}
else if ( $feature.FieldA == 444) {
return "Problem detected"
}
else {

return "No Values"

}
```

Is this even possible in Arcade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is to use a nested [IIF()](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/logical_functions/#iif) statement. Imagine the data is this:

[image: Input]

Then you would run the following field calculate on it using this scripting logic:

```js
var problemValues = [222,333,444];
var v = iif(($feature.fA == 111 && $feature.fB == 111 && $feature.fC == 111), "OK", iif((indexOf(problemValues,$feature.fA) != 0 && indexOf(problemValues,$feature.fB) != 0 && indexOf(problemValues,$feature.fC) != 0),"no values","problem"));
return v;
```

The result being:

[image: Results]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following expression:

```
var problemValues = [222,333,444];
var fields = [
  $feature.fieldA,
  $feature.fieldB,
  $feature.fieldC
];

for (var i in fields){
  var v = fields[i];
  if(IndexOf(problemValues, v) > -1){
    return 'Problem detected';
  }
}

return 'Everything fine';
```

It's a little easier to read, and definitly easier to modify if you want to update the problem values.